# How to use SQL group to filter rows with minimum date value?

Tags: sql, group-by, limit, db2-400

I have the following table:

| STUDENT_CODE | REGION_CODE | COURSE_CODE | SUBMIT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46588225 | N | AAA00004 | 2017-03-16 06:08:40.031000 |
| 85788225 | N | AAA00004 | 2017-03-24 12:14:29.493000 |
| 85789271 | N | AAA00004 | 2017-06-24 12:14:29.493000 |
| 884444 | N | B0006 | 2017-10-05 00:33:08.627000 |
| 2558855 | N | B0006 | 2019-08-02 02:47:22.996000 |

I want to achieve the result which selects only student code having min value of submit_date of region_code and course_code. ie

| STUDENT_CODE | REGION_CODE | COURSE_CODE | SUBMIT_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 46588225 | N | AAA00004 | 2017-03-16 06:08:40.031000 |
| 884444 | N | B0006 | 2017-10-05 00:33:08.627000 |

how can I achieve this using group by and FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY? I have done as follows but it is not working.

```
select a.STUDENT_CODE,a.REGION_CODE,a.COURSE_CODE,min(a.SUBMIT_DATE) from STUDENT as a where a.REGION_CODE='N' and a.COURSE_CODE IN ('AAA00004','B0006') group by a.STUDENT_CODE, a.REGION_CODE, a.COURSE_CODE order by a.COURSE_CODE asc FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: What do you mean "using group by and FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY"?  I mean, you can't.  You need `select` and `from` at least, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `row_number()` for this:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by region_code, course_code order by submit_date desc) as seqnum
      from student s
      where s.REGION_CODE = 'N' and
            s.COURSE_CODE IN ('AAA00004', 'B0006')
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon linoff is working too.

But i have question. Could you tell me, which one will be faster for grouping the large/big data? manual filter in subquery or function row_number() in subquery.

Comment: @mae . . . You would need to try that on your data in your environment.  I would expect this to be faster than an aggregation, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery

```
select a.STUDENT_CODE,a.REGION_CODE,a.COURSE_CODE,SUBMIT_DATE
from STUDENT as a 
where a.REGION_CODE='N' and a.COURSE_CODE IN ('AAA00004','B0006')
and SUBMIT_DATE in
   (select min(SUBMIT_DATE) from STUDENT as b where a.COURSE_CODE=b.COURSE_CODE)
```